# Загрузка большого XML файла Entity Framework

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

Делаю следующим образом. 
Создал класс

```
namespace FenixBookParser.Model
{
    class Book
    {
        [Key]
        public int BookId { get; set; }

        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Author { get; set; }
        public string Publisher { get; set; }
        public string Price_ozon { get; set; }
        public string Price_labirint { get; set; }
        public string Year { get; set; }
        public string ISBN { get; set; }
        //Тираж
        public string Circulation { get; set; }
        public string Series { get; set; }
        public string Format { get; set; }

        public string Page_count { get; set; }
        //Тип обложки
        public string Type_cover { get; set; }
        public string Url { get; set; }
    }
}
```

И затем делаю вот так.

```
 private static BooksContext context = new BooksContext();
        public static void GetBookName()
        {
            XDocument xdoc = XDocument.Load(@"C:\Files\1132527.xml");
            var booksLst = xdoc.Descendants().Select(b =>
            new Book
            {
                Author = b.Element("author")?.Value,
                Name = b.Element("name")?.Value,
                Url = b.Element("url")?.Value,
                Year = b.Element("year")?.Value,
                Publisher = b.Element("publisher")?.Value,
                Series = b.Element("series")?.Value,
                Page_count = b.Element("page_extent")?.Value,
                ISBN = b.Element("ISBN")?.Value,
                Price_ozon = b.Element("price")?.Value


            }).ToList();

            foreach (Book book in booksLst)
            {
                if (book.Name != null)
                {
                    context.Books.Add(book);

                }
                context.SaveChanges();
            }
        }
```

Все работает до определенного момента. Данные заливаются 
нормально, но в выскакивает ошибка

```
An unhandled exception of type 'System.OutOfMemoryException' occurred in mscorlib.dll
```

Может быть дозировано нужно заливать данные?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Тут начало файла http://pastebin.com/wuK1fjDg

Comment: почему бы цикл не запускать только по тем записям которые надо добавить: `foreach (Book book in booksLst.Where(x=>x.Name!=null))`

Comment: если элементов действительно много то почему бы не разбить на порции, и не надо сохранить после добавления 1. добавьте несколько потом сохраняйте

Comment: В какой именно строчке ошибка? Может в сам context такое к-во данных не поместится? Сделайте в коде комментарий `/*тут ошибка*/` может надо пересмотреть сам алгоритм хранения данных.

Comment: добавил скрин с ошибкой. Он не показывает определенного места. Просто выдает эту ошибку

Comment: А что в `xml`, структура, размер?

Comment: Размер около 2ГБ, структуру приложить?

Comment: Ну было бы неплохо) Мне просто лень с нуля все делать чтоб попробовать... 2 гига.. мда)

Comment: проверьте на каком этапе у Вас заканчивается память: при десериализации?

Comment: А почему вообще такая необходимость хранить это в xml? Или это разовая операция?

Comment: Прикрепил начало файла. выдираю инфу из  <offer>. Это разовая операция

Comment: В общем ответ вам уже дан, сначала мной, а потом еще круче Павлом .

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Главная ошибка - вы используете `Descendants()` без уточнений. В итоге, у вас каждый элемент из файла грузится как отдельная книга. Замена запроса на более адекватный (что-то вроде `Descendants("book")` или `Root.Elements()`) уменьшит используемую под список книг память в 10 раз, а время работы - в 100 раз.

---

Но, вообще говоря, это все еще недостаточно. Чтобы ваша программа могла обрабатывать большие объемы данных, вам надо:

1. отказаться от `XDocument` и использовать `XmlReader`;
2. записывать в базу крупными пакетами (скажем, по 100000 книг), а не одним большим куском;
3. отключить в контексте EF автоматическое отслеживание изменений (`context.Configuration.AutoDetectChangesEnabled = false`);
4. очищать контекст после сохранения в базу.

Comment: Могли бы мне подсказать я на правильном пути? Начал переделывать, но сейчас  не могу понять , как мне это делать порцианально и передать в лист данные. Вот ,что я пока написал http://pastebin.com/0rw9NbE4